# How to filter a DataFrame by a function

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

I want to filter a DataFrame using a condition which is passing a function I made. This function will return True or False.

But I get this exception:

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

This is my code:

```
def filter():
    inicio = time.time()
    df = pd.read_csv('data_base.csv')
    nrows = df.shape[0]
    for i in range(nrows).__reversed__():
        coincidencias = df[
            (df['Fecha'] == df.loc[i]['Fecha']) &
            (df['Mercado'] == df.loc[i]['Mercado']) &
            (df['Local'].str.contains(main_word(df.loc[i]['Local']), case=False)) &
            (df['Visitante'].str.contains(main_word(df.loc[i]['Visitante']), case=False)) &
     ---->  (is_there_surebet(df['Contenido'], df.loc[i]['Contenido']))   <----
            ].dropna()

        if coincidencias.shape[0] > 1:
            print(coincidencias)


        df = df.drop([i])
    fin = time.time()
    print(fin-inicio)
```

The line between arrows is the one that cause the exeption. Let me know if the `is_there_surebet` function is necessary to fix the problem, but I think it won't be the case.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to create a function that returns True \ False and apply it on the relevant columns. Please check if you find the following example helpful -

```
def my_filter(x):
    return x > 0

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, -4, 5, -3], "y": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]})
df[df["x"].apply(my_filter)]
```

The results will be only the rows where the value in column `x` is greater than 0.

For something more sophisticated that requires input from multiple columns, you can use something like this -

```
def my_filter(record):
    if record["x"] < 0:
        return False
    return record["y"] in ["a", "b", "c"]

df[df.apply(my_filter, axis=1)]
```

**Edit** - adding more examples

If you want to use a parameter you can do -

```
def my_filter(record, my_param):
    if record["x"] < my_param:
        return False
    return record["y"] in ["a", "b", "c"]

df[df.apply(lambda x: my_filter(x, 5), axis=1)]
```

Comment: I saw something like that before. But unfortunately, that is not what I'm looking for. I wonder if there is any method in DataFrame class, that allows me to pass the cell as an argument. I'll give an example. Imagine I'm using that function you just defined. But instead of passing "0" as an argument, I'm going to be using another element from the DataFrame, like x > X_o where X_o is the element in position (0,0). Is that actually possible?

Comment: Is this element in the same record, i.e row or somewhere else?

Comment: Not in the same row or column but in the same Dataframe

Comment: Is it the same for all the rows? if so extract it and used it as a parameter. Please see the example I just added

Comment: Not exactly. I use a list of parameters but it doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: I fail to understand the logic you are looking for and therefore cannot suggest a solution

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured it out. But thank you so much for your time!